# Django & Celery & Rabbit getting Not Registered error

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

I am trying to set up Django & Celery & Rabbit for the first time following this [tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/20/how-to-use-celery-with-django.html). I am using Django 2.0 Celery 4.2.0 and Rabbit on Windows

I am getting the error: celery.exceptions.NotRegistered: 'GeneratePDF'

I have set up as follows:

in my **init**.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import celery
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

in my celery.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'abc.settings')

app = Celery('abc')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

in my tasks.py:

```
from celery import shared_task
from abc.celery import app
@shared_task(name='GeneratePDF')
class GeneratePDF(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      ....
```

in my views.py:

```
from abc.tasks import GeneratePDF

@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class ClientProfilePDF(RedirectView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        GeneratePDF.delay(request)
        return  HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
```

in my settings.py:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://localhost'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Australia/Sydney'
CELERY_IMPORTS = ('abc.tasks',)
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to where I am going wrong and why I am getting this error? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two quick things:

1. No need for any parameters to `app.autodiscover_tasks()`  Celery alreayd knows how to use `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`.
2. The `@shared_task` decorator is for tasks that live in apps that do not have their own `celery.py` file that instantiates an app.  From the looks of it, your `tasks.py` file lives in the same django app as the `celery.py` file.  In this case, you should use `@app.task` and not `@shared_task`.

before you start, you can get a list of registered tasks by doing `celery -A myapp inspect registered`.  That will let you see if your `GeneratePDF` task is registered or not.